# How to store user defined scoring formulas?

Tags: mysql, database-design

First post, so apologize if I have not chosen the best spot for it:

If I had table of values, let's say corresponding to a question number and its corresponding answer, what is the correct way to plan a database to allow users to store formulas to calculate a score based on said answers?

#### Example:

Let's say I have a table of answer given to a series of questions:

Question_and_answer_table

`ID   Answer
 1       3
 2       5
 3       7
 4       9`

Then I have 3 different users, User1, User2, User 3.

If I want each user to be able to define how they want to weigh the answers to determine a final score

> ex: User1: A1*3-A2*2+A3*7*A4=SCORE

what's the best way to handle storing a formula for each user?

Thank you for your time and help!

Cheers

Comment: Will the number of questions always be the same?

Comment: Whatever is most convenient for your application language.  PHP?  Java?  Whatever?

Comment: @Vérace Thanks for replying.  No - this is more of a hypothetical. Was trying to better understand how to build this type interaction so I can expand on it.

Comment: @RickJames -  I work mainly with PHP and Mysql.  More of a database planning (diagramming) question. Apologies if this was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a table of weights -- that is, an association of user with each question and how much that answer is weighted. Then you can give each user their own weight for each answer.

```
create table Weights(
    UserID     int not null references Users( ID ),
    AnswerID   int not null references Answers( ID ),
    Weight     int default 1, -- For Ux: Ax * Weight,
    constraint PK_Weights primary key( UserID, AnswerID )
);
```

I've shown the weight as an integer but you can change that if you want fractional values (A1 * 3.5 + A2 * -2.75 + A3 * 7 + A4 * 3.1415 = SCORE ).

Comment: Thank you @TommCatt.  This was very helpful.  Essentially break the weights down by User-and-Answer combo, and call individual weighting when calculating the score.  I appreciate your time and help.  Cheers.